# How to find the right constraints on a canonical transformation?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

I have a 1-dof Hamiltonian in the variables $p,q$. I am not sure on how to find the constraints on a canonical tansformation $\psi(P,Q)=(p,q)$ such that the Hamiltonian in the new variables $P$ and $Q$ has the form
\begin{equation}
H\circ\psi\ (P,Q) = K(P,Q) = \alpha(P)+\beta(Q)
\end{equation}
for some (unknown) functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

In practice, I'd like to "separate" the variables $P$ and $Q$.
Apart from seeing that $\dot{Q}=\alpha'$ and $\dot{P}=-\beta'$ I get tangled in partial derivatives. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, one can choose the Kamiltonian $K=\alpha(P)$ to be a function of the new momenta $P_i$ only, i.e., $\beta\equiv 0$,  by solving the time-independent [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) for Hamilton's characteristic function $W$, which (for a $2n$-dimensional phase space) is a [first-order non-linear PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation) in $n$ variables. Of course in practice, this is easier said than done.

Comment: Of course, but maybe loosening the constraints on $K$ could be a compromise; this hope motivates the form $K(P,Q)=\alpha(P)+\beta(Q)$...